# isspace : Need to identify only space not other characters

Tags: c, string

I have this piece of code where SAS is calling a C program to read/write to a VSAM file .

```
char *ltrim(char *s)
{    
    while(isspace(*s)) s++;

    return s;    
}

char *rtrim(char *s)
{     
    char* back = s + strlen(s);

    while(isspace(*--back));

    *(back+1) = '\0';

    return s;    
}

char *trim(char *s)
{    
    return rtrim(ltrim(s));    
}
```

It is called this way

```
strlen(trim(XXXX))
```

Values like `99999899.99` are present in `XXXX`. This is written into a COMP-3 filed in the VSAM file. So in hex the value that will be written to the output file will be ending with `0X99`,`0X89`,`0X90`,`0X0C`.

I found an issue where the program removes the `0C` in the `trim` function. The `rtrim` function does it only when the value is `99999899.00`. If value is `99999899.99` then no issue is observed. If value is less than `99999899.00` no issue is observed. I found it quite strange till i read that the `isspace` function considers all the below as well ( http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isspace/ ):

- `' ' (0x20) space (SPC)`
- `'\t' (0x09) horizontal tab (TAB)`
- `'\n' (0x0a) newline (LF)`
- `'\v' (0x0b) vertical tab (VT)`
- `'\f' (0x0c) feed (FF)`
- `'\r' (0x0d) carriage return (CR)`

I am pretty sure the author is looking to remove only spaces. So in short, I want to remove only spaces and not (0X0c) Feed (FF) . So what can I replace these 2 lines with

```
while(isspace(*--back));
*(back+1) = '\0';
```

Comment: First of all, you are not being clear as to why the output of `strlen(trim(99999899.99))` should be `0X99,0X89,0X90,0X0C`. Second, I am pretty sure the author **DOES** actually want to remove **all types** of white spaces. Third, function `rtrim` will most likely cause a memory access violation if all characters in the input string are white spaces.

Comment: Well, i am repairing someone work so i am not aware of the exact intentions of the author to be frank.  Well , the COMP-3 variable storage is a compression methof which should have a 0X0C in the end. so a comp-3 variable from a SAS program is passed to C program and and thr rtrim does this removal only for the case where the value is 99999899.00 and not for any other values.  This is the mystery. 
What i need is a replacement of this isspace in this scenarios as i know vert little C . 
Thanks for your comment !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `isspace(X)` with `X == ' '`

BTW, the `rtrim` function causes undefined behaviour if the string consists completely of spaces (or the string is empty), it will run off the front of the array. You might want to re-design it, or at least make it stop when it hits the front.

Comment: Thanks MAtt ,
Can you help me rewrite the code in the method you suggested ?

Comment: I am quite new to this and i am not able to rewrite the code

Comment: Change `while(isspace(*--back)); *(back+1) = '\0';` to `while ( back != s && back[-1] == ' ' ) { --back; }  back[0] = '\0';`

Comment: The newlines don't matter